# How to parse bitcoin blockchain blkxxxxx.dat files, especially transaction parts

Tags: python, parsing, blockchain, block, bitcoin

I have tried pyblockchain package from emcpow2. But this package seems just return header information. What I really need is the transaction scripts and address. As in the picture shows, there is no transaction scripts method

Is there any other way [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szr5m.png)to parse blkxxxxx.dat files or am I using this package incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste your code inline.

Answer (score 0):

Just parse as:

```
      for transaction in block.transactions:
          for output in transaction.outputs:
              for addr in output.addresses:
                  print(addr.address)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended to read binary files directly, because there should be a change in the binary format.

Alternatively, please use [REST API](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/REST-interface.md) instead.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8332/rest/blockhashbyheight/1.json 
$ curl http://localhost:8332/rest/block/00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048.json
```